# Drupal 7 unable to reach CiviCRM installer

Tags: installation

I'm trying to install CiviCRM (4.6.10) on a fresh copy of Drupal 7 (7.41) but I can't start the CiviCRM installer.

**Error messages:**
When I visit http://your_domain_or_IP_address/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php I get a Server Error 500. Looking at my logs they read:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR/civicrm/civicrm//CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php:/usr/local/php56/lib/php') in /home/hostname/public_html/test/d7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 75
PHP Warning:  require_once(WP_PLUGIN_DIR/civicrm/civicrm//CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/hostname/public_html/test/d7/sites/all/modules/civicrm/install/index.php on line 75
```

From Drupal

```
Notice: Undefined index: description in drupal_check_module() (line 1232 of /home/hostname/public_html/test/d7/includes/install.inc).
(Currently using CiviCRM settings does not exist CiviCRM settings file does not exist. It should be created by CiviCRM install)
```

**What I've tried:** setting folder permissions to 755 or 777. I have uploaded the CiviCRM files via ftp and also using the URL. I have re-installed Drupal 7.

I was able to successfully install CiviCRM on Wordpress on the same server but I'm stuck on the Drupal install.

To be clear, I downloaded and uploaded different CiviCRM installation. One specific to Wordpress (for Wordpress) and one for Drupal. The modules show up in my Drupal Modules section.

Any idea what I can do to kick start the installer?

Comment: Can you clear the browser cache/cookies(mostly using `Ctrl+Shift+Del`) and check ?

Comment: That worked! I tried it in an incognito window and the installation came up. I can't believe I didn't try that :( Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

It mentions WP_PLUGIN, are you sure you downloaded the civicrm version for drupal, and not the one for wordpress?

You can't just re-use the same civicrm code base between wordpress and drupal, you'll need to download the CMS specific version again

X+

Comment: I thought the same thing when I saw that but I got it from their download page and the file is named "civicrm-4.6.10-drupal". Odd. I re-installed it twice as well and it shows up in my Modules in Drupal? Also the installation file I have uploaded looks like it is both for Drupal and Wordpress. There is an if statement checking if the CMS is Drupal or Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

"CiviCRM has been successfully installed"!

The solution in my case was suggested by "jitendrapurohit" by clearing my cookies and cache. I re-opened the installer in an incognito window and it came up the first time and installed successfully.

Comment: I'm pleased that worked.  Could you mark this as the accepted answer in case other people have the same problem - click on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

My thoughts too Xavier, it is strange that it starts looking for WP_PLUGIN if you are indeed using the Drupal installer